# Content with queryui checkbox button grows when is replaced with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have the next code to replace content using Backbone.js

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vicenrele/Thxtr/1/)

I don't know why the checkbox button grows when the content is replaced.
Simply, I use the next code to checkbox

```
 $('.checkWeek').button();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is because you keep calling the `$('.checkWeek').button();` on every click so JQuery does something funny and adds a `span` within a `span` which causes the size to grow.

A simple fix is to not call the `$('.checkWeek').button();` if the button already exists (or shown)

```
// if button already exists then dont add it again.
if(!$('label[for=checkWeekM]').hasClass('ui-button'))
      $('.checkWeek').button();
```

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Thxtr/3/

Comment: If the content is reload and the button was checked, the button loads disable until the content is reload again. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment code stores the templates in `div` tags -  every time you call `button` the template is modified. You can avoid that by using a `script` tag with type `text/template` so that it won't be executed as Javascript.

Rigth now:

```
<div data-template-name="central-home">
    <div data-template-name="">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkWeek" id="checkWeekM" />
        <label for="checkWeekM">L</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Change to:

```
<script data-template-name="central-home">  
    <div data-template-name="">
         <input type="checkbox" class="checkWeek" id="checkWeekM" /><label for="checkWeekM">L</label>
    </div>      
</script>
```

With the Javascript unchanged the template will not be found. So you also have to update this line:

```
 content.view = ...$.trim($("[data-template-name='"+ template_name +"'] div").html()...
```

With the requirement for the template to be inside a div removed:

```
content.view = ...$.trim($("[data-template-name='"+ template_name +"']").html() ...
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Thxtr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `$('.checkWeek').button()` only needs to be called once per `.checkweek` element, or maybe just once in total.

If so then possible workarounds would be :

1. to execute `$('.checkWeek').button()` conditionally (though I'm not sure what the test might be).
2. to make the `$('.checkWeek')` selector more selective, ie select only the freshly added element.
3. if a destroy option exists, to call `$('.checkWeek').button('destroy').button()` (or similar - you will have to search through the plugin's API documentation).

Without a more complete understanding of the app (and the plugins), I can't tell which of these possibilities is most appropriate.