# How to unlock a jquery ui check button when content is replaced with Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

I have a web application which replaces content. This content has jquery ui check buttons. When I replace the content if a button already exists then don't add it again:

```
if(!$('label[for=checkWeekM]').hasClass('ui-button'))
      $('.checkWeek').button();
```

If I push the button (its state is checked) and if I replace the content, the button starts locked until the same content is replaced again.

I use Backbone.js to replace the content

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vicenrele/Thxtr/4/)

How can I unlock the check button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are duplicating `id` attributes and that leads to bad HTML, bad HTML leads to frustration, frustration leads to anger, etc.

You have this in your template that you have hidden inside a `<div>`:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkWeek" id="checkWeekM" />
<label for="checkWeekM">L</label>
```

Then you insert that same HTML into your `.content-central`. Now you have two elements in your page with the same `id` attribute and two `<label>` elements pointing to them. When you add the jQuery-UI button wrapper, you end up with a slightly modified version of your `<label>` as the visible element for your checkbox; but, that `<label>` will be associated with two DOM elements through the `for` attribute and everything falls apart.

The solution is to stop using a `<div>` to store your templates. If you use a `<script>` instead, the browser won't parse the content as HTML and you won't have duplicate `id` attributes. Something like this:

```
<script id="template-central-home" type="text/x-template">
    <div data-template-name="">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkWeek" id="checkWeekM" />
        <label for="checkWeekM">L</label>
    </div>
</script>
```

and then this to access the HTML:

```
content.view = new ContentView({
    model: content,
    template: $('#template-' + template_name).html()
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/qffsm/

There are two quick lessons here:

1. Having valid HTML is quite important.
2. Don't store templates in hidden `<div>`s, store them in `<script>`s with a `type` attribute other than `text/html` so that browser won't try to interpret them as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I took a detailed look at your fiddle after you mentioned this problem. The solution I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716164/content-with-queryui-checkbox-button-grows-when-is-replaced-with-backbone-js/14716863#14716863) was more like a quick fix.

If you want to follow the right thing to avoid long term problems and side effects you should consider what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14716759/827110). This way your problem is solved and there are no other bugs.